# What do you call a piece of jewellery if it is finely crafted? Ornate vs Filigree

Tags: word-choice, word-request

For a example, a brooch, which has a lot of details of high quality.

I found that next options may work:

***Ornate***

> An ornate building, piece of furniture, or object is decorated with complicated patterns or shapes. **Collins**

> elaborately or excessively decorated **Merriam-Webster**

***Filigree***

> 1. delicate ornamental work of twisted gold, silver, or other wire
> 2. any fanciful delicate ornamentation **Collins**

> 1: ornamental work especially of fine wire of gold, silver, or copper applied chiefly to gold and silver surfaces
> 2: ornamental openwork of delicate or intricate design **Merriam-Webster**

Which one is more idiomatic and why? Are there another options?

Comment: *Jewellery/Jewelry* is a mass noun, so you can't say "*a* jewellery", you have to say "a piece of..." or "an item of..."

Comment: @stangdon Thanks, duly noted.

Comment: Presumably you saw that "filigree" is a noun while "ornate" is an adjective. Also, while the words apply to different kinds of items, their meanings can overlap. Thus, it's not an either / or situation, as you seem to suggest.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Good point, I didn't notice actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Filigree](https://www.designlimitededition.com/ancient-art-filigree-world-luxury-design/) describes a particular type of ornate jewellery, as described in the definition you found (i.e. using fine wires). An item of jewellery can be ornate without being filigree work.

Answer (score 1):

> *For a example, a brooch, which has a lot of details of high quality.*

***Brooch***

> A brooch is a small piece of jewellery which has a pin at the back so it can be fastened on a dress, blouse, or coat. **Collins**

> an ornament that is held by a pin or clasp and is worn at or near the neck  **Merriam-Webster**

With that in mind, I think that, of the 2, "ornate" would be a better fit. 
Filigree is a bit too narrow and so might not fit certain contexts.

---

> *Are there another options?*

After searching many words, I found one that fits your case: 
[**bijou**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bijou).
Almost all other words related to jewelry either convey the piece being rare or cheap or showy (last one sometimes qualifying for the person too).

If "***one-word***" isn't a restriction, then for ease of understanding of audience or to not make speech grandiose one may use the following phrase:
[**exquisite jewellery**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exquisite#:%7E:text=adj-,1.,and%20pleasing%3A%20an%20exquisite%20face.)

Comment: I am not so sure that *bijou* is the appropriate word.  As an AmE speaker, I have never used or heard the word.  Maybe it's more common in the UK.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther you'll find the link helpful. Kindly check it.

Comment: I followed the link for bijou and familiarized myself with the meaning.  My point was that most people will have no idea what *bijou* means.  If the best word is a word no one understands, it may not be the best word.  *Bijou* is also a noun.  Can you illustrate how it would be used to describe a piece of exquisite jewelry?  *The Hope Diamond reminds me of a bijou?*  Do I need to coin a new adjective?  *It was a bijouleous diamond?*

Comment: I really like the word *bijouleous*.  I mean I **really** like it.  I might start using it.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther here are some examples found from net for bijou: 1. Hers had just presented her with a lovely coupe, lined with yellow satin, a perfect bijou. 2. The footman showed him into the small drawing-room of the baroness, a bijou of a room, furnished in gilt and crimson satin.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I agree with "most people will have no idea what bijou means". That's why I also mentioned "exquisite jewelry" for exactly the same reason. But then again many authors use such (rare) words rather richly and that too since times old, making a strong case for existence of google in those ages (XD). Or perhaps they at least had a foresight of it for future readers. (XD).

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I'm pretty sure I've heard the term bijou in the context of specifically Cajun culture (which uses a lot of French-origin words), but that was when I was living in Louisiana. I otherwise agree with you that it's not likely to be recognised by most English speakers.

Comment: I am a UK English speaker, and I know what 'bijou' means. Small and attractive. A 'bijou residence' is what UK [real] estate agents call a small house or apartment, often to make it sound fashionable and attractive. Incidentally my cousin had a car called a Citroën Bijou which was a plastic-bodied UK version of the Citroën 2CV produced in small numbers around 1959-1964 (it didn't sell, much, only 210 models). He said it was ugly, slow, and tiny, and  these were part of its charm (maybe that's a British trait, to like ugly ducklings?). Survivors fetch an eye-watering sum nowadays.

Comment: My sister just told me that when she was dating a short guy, a catty acquaintance called him her 'bijou boyfriend'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that acquaintance was either a jeweler or great at English. Nice to see a real-life example though.

Comment: @InanimateBeing - My sister's acquaintance is a normally fluent UK English native speaker.